# How to count event in the last hour grouping by minute

Tags: esper

I have an object that contain a timestamp,

```
class Event{ public long timestamp; }
```

Now I what to count all events in the last hour grouping by minutes.
So I am expecting 60 result.

The query I have try but that give me syntax error near snapshot:

```
select timestamp.roundFloor(''min'') as timeminute, count(1) 
   from Event
   where timestamp.after(current_timestamp.minus(60 minutes)) 
   group by  timeminute  
   snapshot every 15 sec
```

How do I build such a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its "output snapshot" and not just "snapshot", see docs.